# Domain & IP pair reputation

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, ip, mx-record

Recognition a pair a of domain & IP with positive history builds reputation in the eyes of many ISPs. But how does this relation looks like? How important is Domain rep vs IP rep? Can I use many domains with the same IP and they will be treated as new "persona" ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a provider post their algorithm for deciding the reputation of a domain other than what you find in common spam filters.

Based on my own anecdata I've never managed a mail server that got a bad reputation after I set up outbound spam filtering, and applied appropriate SPF and DKIM records and an aggressive DMARC policy to go with them. That includes everything from 2000+ mailbox production systems, dev and test environments for in-house developed software, down to the email server for my private domain.

In short: If you make sure it's hard to abuse your mail servers and domain names, your domain reputation is unlikely to become bad.

Comment: Hi Mikael ;) I'm not sure we're talking about the same case scenario...

What I try do achieve is best sending reputation which is built over time among different ISPs (mailbox providers) while using many domains and IPs.

What I'd like to know is HOW new/fresh domains affects reputation (hence deliverability) when IP is already warmed-up AND vice versa?